# Bootstrap navbar rails gem glypicon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I just added the [gem rails-bootstrap-navbar](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-navbar) to my rails project and I would like to be able to add a glyphicon in front of my dropdown menu, there is no problem to do it with a menu-item but for the dropdown itself, there is no example in the [documentation](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/bootstrap-navbar/wiki/Usage-with-Bootstrap-3). Since the dropdown is already a block, I have no idea how to add a span to it.

```
= navbar fixed: :top do
  = navbar_header brand: 'My great app', brand_link: '/home'
  = navbar_collapse do
    = navbar_group class: 'foo', id: 'menu' do
      = navbar_text 'Pick an option:'
      = navbar_item "Home", '/'
      = navbar_item "About Us", '/about-us'
      = navbar_item '/contact' do
        %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-hand-right
        Contact Us!
      = navbar_dropdown "I want an icon too :-(" do
        = navbar_item '/contact' do
        %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-hand-right
        I can easily have an icon :-)
        - if true # check if user is admin, maybe like "if current_user.try(:admin?)"
          = navbar_dropdown_divider
          = navbar_item "Admin Dashboard", '/admin'
          = navbar_item "Users", '/admin/users'
    = navbar_group align: 'right' do
      - if true # check if user is logged in, maybe like "if current_user.present?"
        = navbar_item "Log Out", '/logout'
      - else
        = navbar_item "Log In", '/login'
```

The exact part I'd like to change

```
          = navbar_dropdown "I want an icon too :-(" do
            = navbar_item '/contact' do
            %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-hand-right
            I can easily have an icon :-)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to do that like, below

```
= navbar_item "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Users".html_safe, '/admin/users'
```

I think you will help

Comment: Thank you very much, that's perfect !